# Drupal content slider like ImageFlow and GalleryFormatter

Tags: 7, javascript

I am looking for Drupal modules that allows to create content sliders (img,audio,video) like [ImageFlow](https://drupal.org/project/imageflow) and [GalleryFormatter](https://drupal.org/project/galleryformatter).

But those modules supports only images.

Are there any modules for creating content sliders like above?

Comment: Why dont you use the mentioned sliders?

Comment: @NikhilM as I mentioned those modules works well only with images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Views slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) will do the job for you:

> Views Slideshow can be used to create a slideshow of any content (not
>   just images) that can appear in a View. Powered by jQuery, it is
>   heavily customizable: you may choose slideshow settings for each View
>   you create.

Answer (score 0):

You could also take a look at [Nivo Slider](http://drupal.org/project/nivo_slider) project.